# Use CURRENT_YEAR, name & age to assign the following string to the header 2 (h2) tag named helloNameOutput:

Tags: javascript, function, variables, input, output

For my assignment working more on input and output. The leactures leading up to this were assigning  doing input and output then working with variables using const, var and lets then getting it to show webpage  example below

```
  let amount = Number.parseFloat("123.12A");
   
   showMessage (amount);
```

```
bellow is what we were instructed to do I  it does everything  shows what ever typed and clears everything when done everything seams to work fine   except in pluralsight when it grades over my work its says I failed to do line 13 that so idk what I did wrong can someone help?
```

```
function displayHello() {

  const  CURRENT_YEAR = 2022 
 let  name = document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value,
    age =    document.getElementById("ageInput").value 

   document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerHTML  = "Hello " + name + " your age is " + age + "  The year you were born in " +  eval(CURRENT_YEAR - age)

  //To DO:
  //Assign the current year to a constant named CURRENT_YEAR.
  //Assign the name entered in the helloNameInput text box to a variable named name.
  //Assign the age entered in the ageInput text box to a variable named age.
  //Use CURRENT_YEAR, name & age to assign the following string to the header 2 (h2) tag named helloNameOutput:
  //Hello Tom. Your age is 39. The year you were born is 1983
  //Please note that this is the output if the name of Tom and age of 39 is entered by the user.
}

function clearName() {
  document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerHTML  = ""
  document.getElementById("helloNameInput").value=""
  document.getElementById("ageInput").value=""
  //To Do:
  //Clear the string in the helloNameInput text box
  //Clear the string in the ageInput text box
}
```

I haven't tried anything else yet because it seams to do what want it to do already.

Comment: *failed to do line 13* ... what does that even mean? what is the "line 13" - why would you `eval(CURRENT_YEAR - age)` when you can `(CURRENT_YEAR - age)` for the same result?

Comment: What is expected: `Hello Tom. Your age is 39. The year you were born is 1983`  vs what your code produces: `Hello Tom your age is 39  The year you were born in 1983` - at least 4 differences there

Comment: Yes It is  supposed to display the name  and what ever age listed then  taking that info and also  displaying  your birth year,  so its working  I just don't get what he wants me to me to do for line 13  when he states Use CURRENT_YEAR, name & age to assign the following string to the header 2 (h2)     on the index.html page the  h2 is <!--Name output-->
    <h2 id="helloNameOutput"></h2>

Comment: So, you can't see the difference between the expected result and what you're doing? There's at least 4 differences - I'm also thinking that the current year should be whatever the current year is when the program is run, not hard coded to the current year when the program was written

Comment: I received a 90. - 10 points for the one I missed. It does everything I need it to do. You see the comments those were the instructions. I  was asked to follow them. I then submit the work online and the computer grades it according to the instructions.  The computer stated I FAILED to  " Use CURRENT_YEAR, name & age to assign the following string to the header 2 (h2) tag named helloNameOutput:"  I don't get how I got the expected results but still missed/failed that part of the instructions.  Using the instructions how else could I have entered the info to get the same results?

Comment: because you did NOT get the expected results - if you can't see the FOUR differences between `Hello Tom. Your age is 39. The year you were born is 1983` (expected) and `Hello Tom your age is 39  The year you were born in 1983` (your output), then I'm afraid there's no helping

Comment: Oh well, I did notice the periods. I attempted to input the code using them and kept getting an error. I asked a few other classmates they said we should be graded by that so I stopped trying. but now looking back that is it.